# Is there a way to have Emmet auto expand HTML tags inside a string inside a script tag?

Tags: javascript, html, visual-studio-code, emmet

I'm using VS Code and would like to be able to expand in this situation.

[image]

I have this inside my config:

```
  "emmet.includeLanguages": {
    "javascript": "html",
  }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a fix for this?

Answer (score -3):

I don't think so. That `const` contains a `string`, and Emmet is recognizing **that**.
Do it in the HTML, cut and paste it inside de `const`'s string.

Comment: Check out this section from Wes Bos's video: https://youtu.be/y4gZMJKAeWs?t=13m

Seems like he does it there.

Comment: Also, this works in a js file. Just not in a script tag.